# Select all checkbox checks except disabled checkboxes using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Trying to Select all checkbox checking and need to restrict disabled checkboxes and check only enabled checkboxes, but all checkboxes are selecting(all enabled and disabled checkboxes are checking). Please suggest me,

```
checkuncheckall() {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    this.displaying_results.forEach(i => {
     this.persons[i].checked = this.isChecked;
    });
  }
```

[Sample Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/avoid-disable-checkboxes-check)

Comment: You could use reactive forms instead of template driven forms.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question shortly - all you need to do is to test for the opposite condition as when you set the control to disabled:

```
this.displaying_results.forEach(i => {
  if(this.persons[i].firstName !== 'Superman'){
    this.persons[i].checked = this.isChecked;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to just check for the checkboxes which are not disabled and perform check/uncheck only those checkboxes, like:

```
checkuncheckall() {
this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
this.displaying_results.forEach(i => {
  if (this.persons[i].firstName !== 'Superman') {
    this.persons[i].checked = this.isChecked;
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to wrap all checkboxes with formarray and when you retrieve your data push for every single data form control inside formarray then bind the formcontrol with it then in the function of select all check if the form control is enable
[here is working example of what i mean.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/avoid-disable-checkboxes-check-vdpfb1?file=app/app.component.ts)
Don't forget to upvote.